# Inline todonotes: Full justification and page breaks?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, todonotes

I frequently use inline `\todo`s (from the famous `todonotes` package) to embed meta comments in my documents, e.g.:

```
\todo[inline,caption={}]{
Some notes:
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[1-2]
\item \lipsum[1-2]
\item \lipsum[1-2]
\end{itemize}
}
```

Which gives the following result:

[image: Example]

My main question is: Is it possible to force full justification within a todo note?

And a side question that just came up preparing the above example: Is it possible to have page breaks in a todo note?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`todonotes` uses `tikz` to build the notes as `nodes`.  This means that they can not split over pages, but you can use `tikz` styling commands.  With the latest version of `todonotes` one changes the `notestyleraw` by appending `align=justify`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\tikzset{notestyleraw/.append style={align=justify}}

\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text

\begin{document}

\todo[inline,caption={}]{
Some notes:
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx also for this answer! How would you do a forced page break  in with the todonotes package?

Comment: @Kare You should ask a separate question, and clarify in what structure the page break is meant to apply.

Comment: Thx for your reply! See here for my question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236745/package-todo-cut-off-at-page-end

Comment: @AndrewSwann I would be grateful if you could help me produce literally inline notes without additional space or line breaks as I asked [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/329701/2288).

Comment: FYI: This does not seem to work with newer versions of TeXlive anymore – and I have no idea why. However, I don't need this at the moment, as I would use ```tcolorbox``` for boxes of this size.

Comment: @JBantje Thanks.  The structure of todonotes has changed, so it a different style key that needs to be adjusted.  See my updated answer.