# Package todo - cut off at page end

Tags: todonotes

I am using the `todonotes` package. However, when the `\todo`s get too long  the text goes over the page and cannot be seen. Here is an example of what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text

\begin{document}

\todo[inline,caption={}]{
Some notes:
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Therefore, how can you do a page break in the `todonotes` package, so that the notes go on on the next page?

I appreciate your answers!

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). Please remember that links expire.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thx for this nice welcome! I just changed the link to a workable example.

Comment: For such large content with colored background, don't use `todo` (They are not notes BTW but content `;-)`). You are safe with say, `tcolorbox`.

Comment: @HarishKumar Is it possible to do a page break with `todonotes`? How would an example look like with `tcolorbos`, including page break?

Comment: With `todonotes`, it is difficult though may be possible. I can add an example with `tcolorbox` if you want.

Comment: Thx! Please add the example with `tcolorbox`. My  real problem is that I use todonotes now through the entire document and a change to another package would be extremely hard...

Comment: I have added an answer with `tcolorbox`. Please let me know if it is useful. Also, it is not that difficult to switch over to `tcolorbox` as can be seen from the answer.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thx for your reply. I will try it out. However, I still have the problem that I would have to change around 900 todo comments in our document...

Comment: Sorry about that but you can always search and replace using your editor.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thx, just tried your answer, but there seems to be a problem if urls are saved like that `\url` with the error message: `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph`

Comment: Are you using `url` packages? Check its manual for breaking a long url.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thx for your answer! I had a deeper and closer look into the latex log and found that he actually does not like my newly defined command: `\newcommand{\noteme}[1]{\iftoggle{comments}{\todo[color=yellow]{{[}ME{]} #1}{}}\linebreak}
`. Why can this command not be used inside the colorbox?

Answer (score 5):

`todonotes` uses `tikz` nodes for its contents, and `node` contents can not be broken across pages.

Hence to put large amount of text with a frame and coloured background, `todonotes` is not a good choice. Better use `tcolorbox`. Here is an example as requested.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=orange,colframe=black,enhanced jigsaw,
                   arc=3mm,boxsep=4pt,boxrule=0.5pt,breakable]
Some notes:
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[1]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]