# todonotes: How to make multiple listoftodos?

Tags: todonotes

In this MWE, I made two commands to highlight parts of the text as a reviewer comment, while the comments are colored uniquely to indicate the author whose comment is typeset.

If I want to make two `listoftodos`, each has the comments entries of one author, how can it be done?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,lipsum}

\usepackage[textwidth=2.5cm,colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2.5cm}

\newcommand\stR[2]{% 1st reviewer comment
    \todo[%
    author=1st Reviewer,noline,caption={1st Reviewer #1 Comment},color=blue!20%
    ]%
    {#1 Comment}{\color{blue}{\bfseries#2}}}

\newcommand\ndR[2]{% 2nd reviewer comment
    \todo[%
    author=2nd Reviewer,noline,caption={2nd Reviewer #1 Comment},color=red!50!white%
    ]%
    {#1 Comment}{\color{red}{\bfseries#2}}}

\begin{document}
\listoftodos[Reviewers Comments]
\section{Section}
Text \stR{2nd}{2nd comment of the 1st reviewer} another text\vspace{\baselineskip}
\lipsum[1]\vspace{\baselineskip}
Some text \ndR{1st}{1st comment of the 2nd reviewer} continue text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a homebrewed version here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140310/multiple-lists-of-to-do-notes/168160#168160.  Unfortunately for you, no other answer using `todonotes` arose from that question.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks for your input. I would be grateful if you could adjust your code to make an output close to that of `todonotes` package.

Comment: Unfortunately, that would take more work than I am willing to invest at the moment.  Perhaps someone else will have a suitable idea.  Best wishes.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes your consideration is appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit hackish but imho it should work. Be aware that it assumes that you use hyperref.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[textwidth=2.5cm]{todonotes}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2.5cm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@todonotes@owner{default}
\define@key{todonotes}%
    {owner}{\def\@todonotes@owner{#1}}

\newtoggle{ownerdefault}
\newtoggle{ownerB}


\newcommand\stR[2]{% 1st reviewer comment
    \todo[%
    owner=default,
    author=1st Reviewer,noline,caption={1st Reviewer #1 Comment},color=blue!20%
    ]%
    {#1 Comment}{\color{blue}{\bfseries#2}}}

\newcommand\ndR[2]{% 2nd reviewer comment
    \todo[%
    owner=B,
    author=2nd Reviewer,noline,caption={2nd Reviewer #1 Comment},color=red!50!white%
    ]%
    {#1 Comment}{\color{red}{\bfseries#2}}}



\renewcommand{\@todonotes@addElementToListOfTodos}{%
    \if@todonotes@colorinlistoftodos%
     \addtocontents{tdo}
      {%
       \protect\iftoggle{owner\@todonotes@owner}
         {%
          \protect\contentsline {todo}
            {\protect\fcolorbox{\@todonotes@currentbordercolor}%
                {\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor}%
                {\protect\textcolor{\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor}{o}}%
            \ \@todonotes@caption
            }{\thepage}{\@currentHref}%
          }{}%
       }%
    \else%
      \addtocontents{tdo}
      {%
       \protect\iftoggle{owner\@todonotes@owner}
         {%
          \protect\contentsline {todo}
            {\@todonotes@caption
            }{\thepage}{\@currentHref}%
          }{}%
       }%
    \fi}%

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\toggletrue{ownerdefault}
\section*{Reviewers 1 Comments}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.tdo}{}

\toggletrue{ownerB}
\togglefalse{ownerdefault}
\section*{Reviewers 2 Comments}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.tdo}{}

\togglefalse{ownerB}
\makeatletter \@starttoc{tdo}\makeatother % to trigger the creation of the list

\section{Section}
Text \stR{2nd}{2nd comment of the 1st reviewer} another text\vspace{\baselineskip}
\lipsum[1]\vspace{\baselineskip}
Some text \ndR{1st}{1st comment of the 2nd reviewer} continue text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer restored my faith in LaTeX :). I would like to ask for something overkill if you don't mind. Can I make the entries in each list sorted according to the comment number not to its appearance? For example, if the `2nd comment` is in page 1, while the `1st comment` in page 2, how can I make `listoftodos` print the entry of the `1st comment` before that of `2nd comment`?  I know it is overkill, but it would be much appreciated if you could consider this.

Comment: Additionally, how can I get the same output if I removed the option `colorinlistoftodos`?, because I found it a bit annoying to have the same color for each entry in the same list.

Comment: Regarding the option: You will have to replace the `\addcontentsline{tdo}{todo}{\@todonotes@caption}` with similar code then before the `\else`. I didn't understand your first question, make a new question with an example, but don't expect an answer today.

Comment: I am so sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by similar code.

Comment: I think I figured out how it works without using `colorinlistoftodos` option. All what I needed to do is to revamp the junk piece of code to be `\renewcommand{\@todonotes@addElementToListOfTodos}{%
     \addtocontents{tdo}
      {%
       \protect\iftoggle{owner\@todonotes@owner}
         {%
          \protect\contentsline {todo}
            {\@todonotes@caption}{\thepage}{\@currentHref}%
          }{}%
       }%
    }%`

Comment: yes that's the idea. I just added the code to the branch. It should now work with and without the option,

Comment: I am happy you didn't give up on me :) Many thanks. I think I will ask a new question on how to sort the entries regardless their appearances someday later :)

Comment: If you don't mind, I would like to understand how to address some issues: 1- how to make the page(s) containing listoftodos without numbers, so the article title page always starts at page 1? 2- if I don't have any comments/entries, how can I make the listoftodos page(s) not generated at all? 3- Is there a short way to switch on/off the creation of listoftodos without revamping the whole code? Your consideration is highly appreciated.

Comment: I am sorry, but after testing again the code in some way, I found that normal `\todo` notes are automatically assigned to the toggle `ownerB`, which makes them be listed in its list of todos. Is there any way to make the normal command `\todo` create another normal list of todos without appending its entries to other toggles'?