# todonotes: custom sort of listoftodos entries

Tags: todonotes

Following [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/329792/2288), for this MWE,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength\marginparwidth{0.8\dimexpr(\paperwidth - \textwidth)/2\relax}
\usepackage[textwidth=\marginparwidth]{todonotes}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@todonotes@owner{default}
\define@key{todonotes}%
    {owner}{\def\@todonotes@owner{#1}}

\newtoggle{ownerdefault}
\newtoggle{ownerB}


\newcommand\stR[2]{% 1st reviewer comment
    \todo[%
    owner=default,
    author=1st Reviewer,noline,caption={#1 Comment},color=blue!20%
    ]%
    {#1 Comment}{\color{blue}{\bfseries#2}}}

\newcommand\ndR[2]{% 2nd reviewer comment
    \todo[%
    owner=B,
    author=2nd Reviewer,noline,caption={#1 Comment},color=red!50!white%
    ]%
    {#1 Comment}{\color{red}{\bfseries#2}}}



\renewcommand{\@todonotes@addElementToListOfTodos}{%
    \if@todonotes@colorinlistoftodos%
     \addtocontents{tdo}
      {%
       \protect\iftoggle{owner\@todonotes@owner}
         {%
          \protect\contentsline {todo}
            {\protect\fcolorbox{\@todonotes@currentbordercolor}%
                {\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor}%
                {\protect\textcolor{\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor}{o}}%
            \ \@todonotes@caption
            }{\thepage}{\@currentHref}%
          }{}%
       }%
    \else%
      \addtocontents{tdo}
      {%
       \protect\iftoggle{owner\@todonotes@owner}
         {%
          \protect\contentsline {todo}
            {\@todonotes@caption
            }{\thepage}{\@currentHref}%
          }{}%
       }%
    \fi}%

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\toggletrue{ownerdefault}
\section*{Reviewer \#1 Comments}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.tdo}{}

\toggletrue{ownerB}
\togglefalse{ownerdefault}
\section*{Reviewer \#2 Comments}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.tdo}{}

\togglefalse{ownerB}
\makeatletter \@starttoc{tdo}\makeatother % to trigger the creation of the list

\section{Section}

Text \stR{\#2}{2nd comment of the 1st reviewer} another text\vspace{\baselineskip}

\lipsum[1-2]\vspace{\baselineskip}

Text \ndR{\#3b}{3rd comment of the 2nd reviewer} another text.\vspace{\baselineskip}

\lipsum[1-2]\vspace{\baselineskip}

Some text \stR{\#1}{1st comment of the 1st reviewer} continue text.\vspace{\baselineskip}

\lipsum[1-2]\vspace{\baselineskip}

Text \ndR{\#3a}{1st comment of the 2nd reviewer} another text.\vspace{\baselineskip}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I need to know how to **alphanumerically** sort the entries of `listoftodos` according to the first argument the custom `todo` commands?

For example, I need the first list entries to be sorted like:

#1 Comment

#2 Comment

and the second list entries to be sorted like:

#3a Comment

#3b Comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you will need some tool that sorts the `.tdo`. You really don't want to do this in latex. E.g. if you would switch to lualatex you could do something like this (you could also activate --shell-excape and call some external script):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength\marginparwidth{0.8\dimexpr(\paperwidth - \textwidth)/2\relax}
\usepackage[textwidth=\marginparwidth]{todonotes}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@todonotes@owner{default}
\define@key{todonotes}%
    {owner}{\def\@todonotes@owner{#1}}

\newtoggle{ownerdefault}
\newtoggle{ownerB}


\newcommand\stR[2]{% 1st reviewer comment
    \todo[%
    owner=default,
    author=1st Reviewer,noline,caption={#1 Comment},color=blue!20%
    ]%
    {#1 Comment}{\color{blue}{\bfseries#2}}}

\newcommand\ndR[2]{% 2nd reviewer comment
    \todo[%
    owner=B,
    author=2nd Reviewer,noline,caption={#1 Comment},color=red!50!white%
    ]%
    {#1 Comment}{\color{red}{\bfseries#2}}}



\renewcommand{\@todonotes@addElementToListOfTodos}{%
    \if@todonotes@colorinlistoftodos%
     \addtocontents{tdo}
      {%
       \protect\iftoggle{owner\@todonotes@owner}
         {%
          \protect\contentsline {todo}
            {\protect\fcolorbox{\@todonotes@currentbordercolor}%
                {\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor}%
                {\protect\textcolor{\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor}{o}}%
            \ \@todonotes@caption
            }{\thepage}{\@currentHref}%
          }{}%
       }%
    \else%
      \addtocontents{tdo}
      {%
       \protect\iftoggle{owner\@todonotes@owner}
         {%
          \protect\contentsline {todo}
            {\@todonotes@caption
            }{\thepage}{\@currentHref}%
          }{}%
       }%
    \fi}%

\makeatother
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
function sort_tdo (jobname)
     local lines = {}
    -- read the lines in table 'lines'
     for line in io.lines(jobname) do
      table.insert(lines, line)
    end
    -- sort
    table.sort(lines)
    -- write all the lines
   file=io.open(jobname.."sorted", "w") 
   io.output(file) 
   for i, l in ipairs(lines) do io.write(l, "\n") 
   end
   io.close(file)
   end 
\end{luacode*}

\IfFileExists{\jobname.tdo}{\directlua{sort_tdo("\jobname.tdo")}}{}

\begin{document}
\toggletrue{ownerdefault}
\section*{Reviewer \#1 Comments}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.tdosorted}{}

\toggletrue{ownerB}
\togglefalse{ownerdefault}
\section*{Reviewer \#2 Comments}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.tdosorted}{}

\togglefalse{ownerB}
\makeatletter \@starttoc{tdo}\makeatother % to trigger the creation of the list

\section{Section}

Text \stR{\#2}{2nd comment of the 1st reviewer} another text\vspace{\baselineskip}

\lipsum[1-2]\vspace{\baselineskip}

Text \ndR{\#3b}{3rd comment of the 2nd reviewer} another text.\vspace{\baselineskip}

\lipsum[1-2]\vspace{\baselineskip}

Some text \stR{\#1}{1st comment of the 1st reviewer} continue text.\vspace{\baselineskip}

\lipsum[1-2]\vspace{\baselineskip}

Text \ndR{\#3a}{1st comment of the 2nd reviewer} another text.\vspace{\baselineskip}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following is based on Ulrike's answer and also requires LuaTeX. It has three improvements: It does not read the file line by line but instead reads it in one go (That's often faster), it uses local instead of global variables if possible and uses non-generic names for it's only global variable ([avoiding problems with other code which also uses such variables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511230/error-font-tu-latinmodernroman0-bx-n-10-latinmodernroman)) and doesn't write the sorted lines to a file and instead keeps them in a Lua variable. This avoids messing up Lua's default output stream, doesn't leave another file in your working directory and is faster:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength\marginparwidth{0.8\dimexpr(\paperwidth - \textwidth)/2\relax}
\usepackage[textwidth=\marginparwidth]{todonotes}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\@todonotes@owner{default}
\define@key{todonotes}%
    {owner}{\def\@todonotes@owner{#1}}

\newtoggle{ownerdefault}
\newtoggle{ownerB}


\newcommand\stR[2]{% 1st reviewer comment
    \todo[%
    owner=default,
    author=1st Reviewer,noline,caption={#1 Comment},color=blue!20%
    ]%
    {#1 Comment}{\color{blue}{\bfseries#2}}}

\newcommand\ndR[2]{% 2nd reviewer comment
    \todo[%
    owner=B,
    author=2nd Reviewer,noline,caption={#1 Comment},color=red!50!white%
    ]%
    {#1 Comment}{\color{red}{\bfseries#2}}}



\renewcommand{\@todonotes@addElementToListOfTodos}{%
    \if@todonotes@colorinlistoftodos%
     \addtocontents{tdo}
      {%
       \protect\iftoggle{owner\@todonotes@owner}
         {%
          \protect\contentsline {todo}
            {\protect\fcolorbox{\@todonotes@currentbordercolor}%
                {\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor}%
                {\protect\textcolor{\@todonotes@currentbackgroundcolor}{o}}%
            \ \@todonotes@caption
            }{\thepage}{\@currentHref}%
          }{}%
       }%
    \else%
      \addtocontents{tdo}
      {%
       \protect\iftoggle{owner\@todonotes@owner}
         {%
          \protect\contentsline {todo}
            {\@todonotes@caption
            }{\thepage}{\@currentHref}%
          }{}%
       }%
    \fi}%

\makeatother
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
  local split_lines = lpeg.Ct((lpeg.C((1-lpeg.P'\n')^0)*'\n')^0)*-1
  function sorted_lines_from_filename (jobname)
    local file = io.open(jobname)
    local lines = split_lines:match(file:read'a')
    file:close()
    assert(lines, 'Files should end with a newline')
    table.sort(lines)
    return lines
  end
\end{luacode*}

\IfFileExists{\jobname.tdo}{\directlua{sorted_tdo = sorted_lines_from_filename("\jobname.tdo")}}{}

\begin{document}
\toggletrue{ownerdefault}
\section*{Reviewer \#1 Comments}
\directlua{if sorted_tdo then tex.tprint(sorted_tdo) end}

\toggletrue{ownerB}
\togglefalse{ownerdefault}
\section*{Reviewer \#2 Comments}
\directlua{if sorted_tdo then tex.tprint(sorted_tdo) end}

\togglefalse{ownerB}

\directlua{sorted_tdo=nil} % We no longer need sorted_tdo, so clean up

\makeatletter \@starttoc{tdo}\makeatother % to trigger the creation of the list

\section{Section}

Text \stR{\#2}{2nd comment of the 1st reviewer} another text\vspace{\baselineskip}

\lipsum[1-2]\vspace{\baselineskip}

Text \ndR{\#3b}{3rd comment of the 2nd reviewer} another text.\vspace{\baselineskip}

\lipsum[1-2]\vspace{\baselineskip}

Some text \stR{\#1}{1st comment of the 1st reviewer} continue text.\vspace{\baselineskip}

\lipsum[1-2]\vspace{\baselineskip}

Text \ndR{\#3a}{1st comment of the 2nd reviewer} another text.\vspace{\baselineskip}

\end{document}
```