# Package todonotes: Mark todo notes as done

Tags: todonotes

As I use the package *todonotes*, I need to mark todo notes as done. Henrik, the author of the package, has this feature on the list of *Things to improve*. However, it has not been implemented yet.

I came up with a kind of "dirty" solution that works for me: I am only learning LaTeX now, so I built it around the idea in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386300/a-way-to-check-off-todonotes) as best as I could.

**MWE compiled:**

[image: proposed solution for marking todo notes as done]

**MWE code:**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

% If-else statement for todo notes
\newif\ifshowtodos

% Show existing ToDo notes in this project?
% 'Show' - Uncomment line below; 'Hide' - Comment out
\showtodostrue

\ifshowtodos
   \usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption]{todonotes}
\else
   \usepackage[disable, colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption]{todonotes}
\fi
 
% Mark \todo notes as done by adding a strikethrough, grey color, and
% place such todos in the list "Todo resolved"
\usepackage{newfloat}% for listof
\makeatletter
% If option 'disable' is activated, define empty commands
  \if@todonotes@disabled%
    \newcommand{\listofdonetodos}[1][]{}
    \newcommand{\tododone}[1]{}
  \else
    % Otherwise, define proper commands \todonote and listofdonetodos
    \DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=tdod,listname={Todo resolved}]{donetodo}
    \newcommand{\tododone}[1]{\todo[inline,nolist,color=gray!20,textcolor=gray!70,bordercolor=gray!60]{\sout{#1}}\addcontentsline{tdod}{donetodo}{\sout{#1}}}
  \fi % \if@todonotes@disabled
\makeatother
 
\begin{document}
 
\listoftodos
{\let\clearpage\relax \listofdonetodos}
 
\section{Introduction}
 
\todo[inline]{Add text}
 
Some text.
 
\tododone{Added section title}
 
\end{document}
```

For now, the things I do not like myself:

- In *Todo resolved*, left of the text "Added section title" - the colored box should be preserved (not sure how to do it)
- LaTeX code in general does not seem to look neat/elegant

Please review my solution and **provide your feedback**. Are there ways to improve/refine it?

Once all the feedback is collected, Henrik agreed to take a look at the solution and maybe add it to the package documentation.

Since, I am sure, a lot of LaTeX users, like me, are looking forward to having this feature introduced, why not make a collective contribution to this great package together!