# automatic todo list with priority hierarchy

Tags: packages, todonotes, easy-todo

I've been using the "easy-todo" package, and looked at the "todo" package, for making todo lists automatically. They allow you to write a `\todo{<todo text>}`command, which will both show in-text and be aggregated into a todo list.

**But these packages don't allow you to specify how important or urgent a todo is.**

I would like a todo package that allows you to say: `\todo[2]{<todo text>}` -- where 2 is the "importance" of this todo.

Then the todolist should automatically order the todo items according to importance.

Does this exist?

Comment: For the priority you could use [fixme](https://ctan.org/pkg/fixme), the problem is sorting the list, here something similar with todonotes: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330485/todonotes-custom-sort-of-listoftodos-entries